# AngularJS: recommended way of triggering a function via enter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Consider an application where one can trigger a database search by giving input to a textfield, then pressing enter. The search result should be shown immediately after.

To accomplish this, i created an input element and gave it a directive attribute:

```
<input search-shipment type="text">

// Directive

Shipment.directive('searchShipment',function(){
    return{
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope,element){
            element.bind('keydown',function(e){
                if (e.which === 13){
                    scope.shipment.fetchShipment();
                }
            })
        }
    }
});
```

The function that was triggered:

```
Shipment.prototype.fetchShipment = function(){

    $http.post('../sys/core/fetchShipment.php',{
        // some data to POST

    }).success(function(data){
          console.log(data);
       });
       console.log(finished);
};
```

This caused some weird behaviour. The function was triggered, and "finished" was logged to the console. However, `success()` was apparently triggered to late, `data` was not logged until i made another input which has to be something different than <kbd>return</kbd>

Now i have figured out that i can avoid this behaviour by using a form as a wrapper for my input element, then using ng-submit to trigger my function.

However, i wonder about some things:

- Why has my first, directive based solution not worked properly?
- How can i accomplish my goal without using a form?
- Even with the working form solution, the second `console.log()` is triggered *before* the logging of the data. Why is this?

Comment: As an answer to your third point: `console.log(data)` is within the callback function, which is only triggered after the response to the HTTP request is received. Since `console.log(finished)` is outside the callback, it'll be executed immediately after the HTTP request is made.

Comment: in addition to @godfrzero - $http has `always()` method (since 1.1.5 version) where you can put your `console.log(finished)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hard to diagnose for sure just based on the description, without the live code but are 2 thing to notice here:

- your problem might be linked to using `$http` from AngularJS version 1.1.x where request interceptors were added. As a consequence `$http` calls need to be done from within the `$digest` loop. Try to wrap your call into `scope.$apply` like so:

  ```
  link: function(scope,element){
          element.bind('keydown',function(e){
              if (e.which === 13){
                  scope.$apply(function(){
                    scope.shipment.fetchShipment();
                  });

              }
          })
      }
  ```
- if you are using 1.1.x anyway, you can use an existing [ngKeyDown](http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/docs/api/ng.directive%3angKeydown) directive instead of rolling out your own.